# In the V8 javascript engine, how to make a constructor function that re-uses an ObjectTemplate for each instance?

Tags: c++, v8

I have working code where I can create as many Point objects as I want, but it re-creates the object template each time the constructor is called, which seems like it's probably wrong.

```
Local<ObjectTemplate> global_templ = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);

// make the Point constructor function available to JS
global_templ->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Point"), FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, v8_Point));
```

and then the constructor itself:

```
void v8_Point(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    HandleScope scope(args.GetIsolate());

    // this bit should probably be cached somehow
    Local<ObjectTemplate> point_template = ObjectTemplate::New(args.GetIsolate());
    point_template->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

    point_template->SetAccessor(String::NewFromUtf8(args.GetIsolate(), "x"), GetPointX, SetPointX);
    point_template->SetAccessor(String::NewFromUtf8(args.GetIsolate(), "y"), GetPointY, SetPointY);
    // end section to be cached

    Local<Object> obj = point_template->NewInstance();
    Point * p = new Point(1,1);
    obj->SetInternalField(0, External::New(args.GetIsolate(), p));
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(obj);
}
```

But it seems like I should be able to pass in the point_template object instead of re-creating it each time.   I saw that there's a Data() field in args, but that only allows for a Value type and an ObjectTemplate is of type Template, not Value.

Any help on the right way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out finally.

In javascript, when you add a function via a FunctionTemplate and then call it as a constructor (e.g. `new MyFunction`), then in your c++ callback the `args.This()` will be a new object created by the using the `FunctionTemplate`'s `InstanceTemplate` object template.

```
// Everything has to go in a single global template (as I understand)
Local<ObjectTemplate> global_templ = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);

// create the function template and tell it the callback to use
Local<FunctionTemplate> point_constructor = FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, v8_Point);

// set the internal field count so our actual c++ object can tag along
//   with the javascript object so our accessors can use it
point_constructor->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

// associate getters and setters for the 'x' field on point
point_constructor->InstanceTemplate()->SetAccessor(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "x"), GetPointX, SetPointX);

... add any other function and object templates to the global template ...

// add the global template to the context our javascript will run in
Local<Context> x_context = Context::New(isolate, NULL, global_templ);
```

Then, for the actual function:

```
void v8_Point(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {

    // (just an example of a handy utility function)
    // whether or not it was called as "new Point()" or just "Point()"
    printf("Is constructor call: %s\n", args.IsConstructCall()?"yes":"no");

    // create your c++ object that will follow the javascript object around 
    // make sure not to make it on the stack or it won't be around later when you need it
    Point * p = new Point();

    // another handy helper function example
    // see how the internal field count is what it was set to earlier
    //   in the InstanceTemplate
    printf("Internal field count: %d\n",args.This()->InternalFieldCount()); // this prints the value '1'

    // put the new Point object into the internal field
    args.This()->SetInternalField(0, External::New(args.GetIsolate(), p));

    // return the new object back to the javascript caller
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(args.This());
}
```

Now, when you write the getter and setter, you have access to your actual c++ object in the body of them:

```
void GetPointX(Local<String> property,
               const PropertyCallbackInfo<Value>& info) {
  Local<Object> self = info.Holder();

  // This is where we take the actual c++ object that was embedded
  //   into the javascript object and get it back to a useable c++ object
  Local<External> wrap = Local<External>::Cast(self->GetInternalField(0));
  void* ptr = wrap->Value();
  int value = static_cast<Point*>(ptr)->x_; //x_ is the name of the field in the c++ object

  // return the value back to javascript
  info.GetReturnValue().Set(value);
}

void SetPointX(Local<String> property, Local<Value> value,
               const PropertyCallbackInfo<void>& info) {
  Local<Object> self = info.Holder();

  // same concept here as in the "getter" above where you get access
  //   to the actual c++ object and then set the value from javascript
  //   into the actual c++ object field
  Local<External> wrap = Local<External>::Cast(self->GetInternalField(0));
  void* ptr = wrap->Value();
  static_cast<Point*>(ptr)->x_ = value->Int32Value();
}
```

Almost all of this came from here: https://developers.google.com/v8/embed?hl=en#accessing-dynamic-variables

except it doesn't talk about the proper way to make your objects in a repeatable fashion.

I figured out how to clean up the c++ object in the internal field, but I don't have time to put the whole answer here.   You have to pass in a Global object into your weak callback by creating a hybrid field (a struct works well) on the heap that has both the global object and a pointer to your c++ object.  You can then delete your c++ object, call Reset() on your Global and then delete the whole thing.   I'll try to add actual code, but may forget.

Here is a good source:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/src/d8.cc&l=1064 lines 1400-1441 are what you want. (edit: line numbers seem to be wrong now - maybe the link above has changed?)

Remember, v8 won't garbage collect small amounts of memory, so you may never see it.   Also, just because your program ends doesn't mean the GC will run.  You can use isolate->AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory(length); to tell v8 about the size of the memory you've allocated (it includes this in its calculations about when there's too much memory in use and GC needs to run) and you can use    `isolate->IdleNotificationDeadline(1);` to give the GC a chance to run (though it may choose not to).